# What does it mean for a wavevector to terminate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, crystals

In the question we are told that the amplitude of a wave after being diffracted through a crystal is:
$$
S\propto e^{i\mathbf{k\cdot r_D}}\sum_n e^{i(\mathbf{k-k_0)\cdot r_n}}
$$
where $k_0$ is the incident wave vector, $k$ is the scattered wave vector $r_D$ is the observation point and $r_n$ is the position of the nth point in the lattice.

This is a maximum whenever $k_0-k$ is a reciprocal lattice vector.

Then the question asks us to show that any wave vector that satisfies the condition for a maximum terminates on a Brillouin zone boundary.

How can it terminate at a Brillouin zone boundary, its not even a physical point/ what does it mean by terminate?

Comment: The Brillouin zone boundary is not a physical point in the same way the wave vector is not a vector in physical space. Since both are defined in reciprocal space,comparing them is meaningful.

Comment: what does it mean to terminate there though?

Comment: It just means "end", as in "where does the vector end?". I agree it is a bit of an over-complicated way to say it.

Comment: aah so $k_0-k$ is a reciprocal lattice vector and every point in the reciprocal lattice is on the boundary of a Brillouin zone?

Comment: $k-k_0$ is the change in wavevector due to the scattering event. The question is asking what happens when this vector describing the scattering event has a particular relationship to the reciprocal lattice vectors. But that doesn't mean that it *is*  a reciprocal lattice vector.